# How to show values in cs-html in Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two tables Currency and CurrencyConversion. How can I display all Currency Names in index page?

Currency Table

```
public class Currency
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool Status { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SupplierCurrency> SupplierCurrencies { get; set; }

    }
```

CurrencyConversion Table

```
public class CurrencyConversion
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
        public float Rate { get; set; }
        public int CurrencyTo { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("CurrencyFrom")]
        public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
        public virtual Currency currency { get; set; }
        
    }
```

View Model

```
public class CurrencyAndConversionRateViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Currency> Currencies { get; set; } 
        public CurrencyConversion currencyConversion{ get; set; }
        public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var AllConversions = await _db.CurrencyConversion.Include(s => s.currency).Include(t=>t.currency).ToListAsync();

            return View(AllConversions);
        }
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<CurrencyConversion>
    <div>
        @if (Model.Count() > 0)
        {

            <table class="table table-striped border">
                <tr class="table-secondary">
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.CurrencyId)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.CurrencyTo)
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FromDate)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ToDate)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Rate)
                    </th>


                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.CurrencyId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.CurrencyTo)
                </td>


                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.FromDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ToDate)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Rate)
                </td>

                <td>
                    <partial name="_TableButtonPartial" model="item.Id" />
                </td>
            </tr>
                }

            </table>

        }
        else
        {<p> No Conversions Exists</p>}
    </div
```

> 

[currently result is showing...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35Ln0.png)

Please recommend if there is any better approach for such scenarios? I want to store the conversion rates  for available currencies in currency table and in "CurrencyConversion" table I am storing only currency Ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My objective was to get the names of currencies instead of Ids in `CurrencyId` and `CurencyTo` Columns of `Index.cshtml`page.
I figured out solution by creating new view model for `Index.cshtml` page (instead of using `Model` class which was used for creating table).
In this new view model I have added two more fields (to hold names of currencies) and then in `Controller` by creating joins of tables i have extracted the names of currencies  which I passed in View of `Index.cshtml`.
Below is my code. If someone has better approach please assist.

```
public class IndexCurrencyConversionViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FromCurrencyName { get; set; }
        public string ToCurrencyName { get; set; }
        public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
        public float Rate { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var x = (from a in _db.CurrencyConversion
                    join b in _db.Currency on   a.CurrencyId equals b.Id
                    join c in _db.Currency on   a.CurrencyTo equals c.Id

                    select new IndexCurrencyConversionViewModel
                    {
                        Id=a.Id,
                        FromCurrencyName = a.currency.Name,
                        ToCurrencyName = c.Name,
                        Rate = a.Rate,
                        FromDate = a.FromDate,
                        ToDate = a.ToDate
                    }).ToList();


            return View(x);
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
  <div>
        @if (Model.Count() > 0)
        {
            <table class="table table-striped border">
                <tr class="table-secondary">
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FromCurrencyName)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ToCurrencyName)
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FromDate)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ToDate)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Rate)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.FromCurrencyName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ToCurrencyName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.FromDate)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ToDate)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Rate)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <partial name="_TableButtonPartial" model="item.Id" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        }
        else
        {<p> No Conversions Exists</p>}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to store the conversion rates for available currencies in
> currency table and in "CurrencyConversion" table I am storing only
> currency Ids.

Do you want to change the design of these tables?

I think there is no problem with your design for fields such as Name in Currency table.

> How can I display all Currency Names in index page?

If you want to display the Name field in Currency to Index page, you can directly add the following code in view :

Title:

```
  <th>
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.currency.Name)
  </th>
```

Value:

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.currency.Name)
</td>
```

Here is the test result:

[image]